# How to map localhost:8009 to external firiendly URL?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, hosting, confluence

I've installed [Atlassian Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) to my dedicated server (hosted on softlayer.com). I use Windows 2008R2 with IIS7. By default, Atlassian Confluence is installed and works fine on localhost:8009 (not port 80). But I want it to get accessible from some friendly URL such as http://docs.mysite.com

How can I do it? Where can it be configured? Some DNS? CNAME?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have this installation externally visible then there are two things you'll want to do:

- Create a DNS record to point to the IP of the server - this will allow your visitors to access the server via http://docs.example.com/
- Configure your webserver such that you don't need to use the external port.

  - If you were using Apache I'd suggest you look at `mod_proxy`, for IIS I'm hazier on what would be required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Application Request Routing and URL Rewrite to automatically redirect the users to port 8009 without them having to type it - and without them seeing what port they are actually connected to - the article below gives you the basic idea of how to do this.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing